# Google ChartWrapper doesn't work with Histogram charts

Tags: javascript, charts, histogram, google-visualization

I am following [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram_838632b69bba9339da6b460362e8c582.frame?hl=en) example from [Google Chart documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram).

In the project all the existing graphs are plotted using [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class), so by following example I created [this chart](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YadLyG), now all I needed to do was replace the line where new Histogram instance is created with ChartWrapper.

i.e. Replace below code with:

```
let chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(
  document.getElementById("example")
);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Following code:

```
let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: "Histogram",
  dataTable: data,
  options: options,
  containerId: "example_chartwrapper"
});
wrapper.draw();
```

But it doesn't work and I am getting following error:

> Invalid column index 1. Should be an integer in the range [0-0].

I might be missing something very small but I am struggling to understand what. I have read ChartWrapper limitations and apart from events it doesn't seem like it has any other limitation.

[image: Error]

FWIW: I have created [another example with Google's example data](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmzrvZ) and that also doesn't work

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <p>Using new Histogram</p>
        <div id="example" />
      </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <p>Using ChartWrapper</p>
        <div id="example_chartwrapper" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {  
  let data = new google.visualization.DataTable(GetData());

  let options = {
    title: "Approximating Normal Distribution",
    legend: { position: "none" },
    colors: ["#4285F4"],

    //chartArea: { width: '100%' },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [2,2.01,2.02,2.03,2.04,2.05,2.06,2.07,2.08,2.09,2.10,2.11,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.15,2.16,2.17,2.18,2.19,2.20,2.21,2.22,2.23,2.24,2.25,2.26,2.27,2.28,2.29,2.30,2.31,2.32,2.33,2.34,2.35,2.36,2.37,2.38,2.39]
    },

    bar: {
      gap: 0
    },
    histogram: {
      bucketSize: 0.01,
      maxNumBuckets: 400,
      minValue: 2,
      maxValue: 3
    }
  };


      let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'Histogram',
                    dataTable: data,
                    options: options,
                    containerId: "example_chartwrapper"
                });
      wrapper.draw();


  let chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(
    document.getElementById("example")
  );

  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function GetData() {
  return {
    cols: [
      {
        type: "number",
        id: "Ohm",
        label: "Ohm"
      }
    ],
    rows: [
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.27
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.25
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.12
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.12
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.29
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.14
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.12
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.29
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.25
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.22
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.28
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.29
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.26
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.16
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        c: [
          {
            v: 2.18
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#data-format) for Histogram does show needing at least two columns of data in the data table

`Histogram` must process the data differently from `ChartWrapper`,
most likely using the single value for both columns

an easy work around is to add a view on the `ChartWrapper`,
and use the same index for both columns...

```
let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Histogram',
  dataTable: data,
  options: options,
  containerId: "example_chartwrapper",
  view: {  // <-- add view
    columns: [0, 0]
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  function randomNorm() {
    return (
      (Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() -
        3) /
      3
    );
  }

  var arr = [["Counts"]];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    arr.push([randomNorm()]);
  }
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);

  var options = {
    title: "Approximating Normal Distribution",
    legend: { position: "none" },
    colors: ["#4285F4"],
    chartArea: { width: 401 },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [-1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
    },
    bar: {
      gap: 0
    },
    histogram: {
      bucketSize: 0.01,
      maxNumBuckets: 400,
      minValue: -1,
      maxValue: 1
    }
  };

  let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Histogram',
    dataTable: data,
    options: options,
    containerId: "example_chartwrapper",
    view: {
      columns: [0, 0]
    }
  });
  wrapper.draw();

  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(
    document.getElementById("example")
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="example_chartwrapper"></div>
```

or simply use the same value for both columns when loading the data table...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  function randomNorm() {
    return (
      (Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() +
        Math.random() -
        3) /
      3
    );
  }

  var arr = [["x", "y"]];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    var value = randomNorm();
    arr.push([value, value]);
  }
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);

  var options = {
    title: "Approximating Normal Distribution",
    legend: { position: "none" },
    colors: ["#4285F4"],
    chartArea: { width: 401 },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [-1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
    },
    bar: {
      gap: 0
    },
    histogram: {
      bucketSize: 0.01,
      maxNumBuckets: 400,
      minValue: -1,
      maxValue: 1
    }
  };

  let wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Histogram',
    dataTable: data,
    options: options,
    containerId: "example_chartwrapper"
  });
  wrapper.draw();

  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(
    document.getElementById("example")
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="example_chartwrapper"></div>
```